# Tab key changes the position of textfield inside table

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm receiving a weird behavior which is: when using tab key to switch between `TextField` for the **first** time, the position of the `TextField` changes a little. The following screen shot might better explain the situation.

[image]

As shown above, only the position of `TextField` named 'treatmentType' is not changed because it's focused by click event rather than tab key.

Here's my code:

```
class TreatmentContent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            treatmentType: '',
            notes: '',
            status: '',
            location: '',
            crop: '',
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
            treatmentDay: ''
        };
        this.notesToAdd = {
            treatmentType: 'text',
            notes: 'text',
            status: 'text',
            location: 'text',
            crop: 'text',
            firstName: 'text',
            lastName: 'text',
            email: 'text',
            treatmentDay: 'number',
        };
        this.reorgTableRow = this.reorgTableRow.bind(this);
    }

    reorgTableRow() {
        const notesKeys = _.keys(this.notesToAdd);
        const chunkedKeys = _.chunk(notesKeys, 3);
        return _.map(chunkedKeys, (keyChunk, i) => (
            <TableRow selectable={false} key={i} style={{border: 'None'}}>
                {_.map(keyChunk, (keyName, j) => (
                    <TableRowColumn key={j}>
                        <TextField
                            hintText={keyName}
                            floatingLabelText={keyName}
                            type={this.notesToAdd[keyName]}
                            value={this.state[keyName]}
                            onChange={(e, val) => this.handleInpChange(keyName, val)}
                        />
                    </TableRowColumn>
                ))}
            </TableRow>
        ));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Table>
                    <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false}>
                        {this.reorgTableRow()}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone can give me a clue what leads to this behavior. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it's because of `floatingLabelText`. It's initially displayed inside the field as a placeholder, but moves above the field as a title when you click on the field.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks!!! I delete `floatingLabelText` and it works as expected. May I know whether you have any idea how to fix this and keep `floatingLabelText` at the same time? One thing I try to fix this is that instead of wrapping the `TextField` inside `TableRowColumn`, I simply use a div to wrap it and give it the style of `{display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap'}` and it works as expected. But I still don't understand why this behavior happens when I wrap it with table components.

Comment: Now I have to admit that I didn't see all the movements when I first looked at your GIF. And it's really weird that `treatmentType` behaves differently from all the rest.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, this still remains a mystery to me right now :(